# finding the mean of columns in a data frame in R

Tags: r, dataframe, mean

I have a vector that contains 50 data frames of re-sampled data. So all of the column names are consistent in each data frame but the numeric values are different. Each data frame consists of 12 rows. How can I find the mean value of each row in one particular column between the 50 data frames and place the 12 mean values into a new one column data frame?

Comment: They're in a `list`? Add them all up, then divide by the length, `sapply(your_list, colSums) / (12 * length(your_list))`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the mean of a specific column that exists across your list of dataframes into a dataframe of its own, you can use `dplyr` and `purrr`.

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

map2_df(your_list, "column_name", ~summarize_at(.x, .y, mean))
```